# Why dll did not update? Class Library

Tags: .net, dll, class-library

I have 2 projects inside 1 solution and each of the project link to each other when I build to create dll file. But I cannot see the new class that I declared? why?

Comment: Add more details. new class in which project? And how do you link two projects mutually? It is not possible. What do you mean by linking?

Comment: Did you, by any chance, forget to declare your class public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a circular reference, which is not a good idea.
DLL 1 depends on DLL 2, and vice versa.

When you compile the solution, VS.NET will determine which dll to build first, by looking at the dependencies.  However, since you have a circular dependency, VS.NET will not be able to do this consistently.
It may have built the DLL which contains your new class last, so the referencing DLL doesn't reference to the newest / latest compiled version.

Comment: Frederik, he cant even add references that way in the first place!! VS wont let him. So thats a pre-compile time error! :)

Comment: I add the new class in the first project and I build seperately but still cannot use the new class? how to solve it?

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, I have solved it. I need to cut the circular linking.

Answer (score 0):

please check the access level of tat class.

Please [inheritance concept](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_inheritance.htm)  this could be the problem..
and if this is not the prob just remove that dll reference and before adding it again build the project of which you want to add the reference.